# how properly achieve height 100%

Tags: html, css, height

How to achieve webpage's content container fluently resize, without specifying height=100% or height=auto ? As some of you know it occasionally works properly this way :/ 
Just like here :

http://net.tutsplus.com/ ,  designshack.co.uk

or on facebook ?

On both designshack and nettuts I'm not even able to break up the layout.

Comment: sticky footer? or html, body { height:100%; } ?

Comment: if my firebug is still working properly - none of these. For example here on stackoverflow it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (from ["Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101978), chapter 12) is to use your CSS to set your body with a margin of zero. This will ensure that the main page content takes up all the available room.

For example:

```
body {
       ...
       margin: 0px;
       ...
}
```

You can use similar margin padding on any section defined by a `div` as well. The chapter I referenced has a number of good examples on additional layout options for liquid (auto-resizing) designs.